# Network share Bare Metal Restore not seeing images

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, bare-metal

My 2012 Essentials R2 server is backed up to an ISCSI drive. Yesterday both disks in my RAID0 decided to die, so I am having to do a BMR from the backup. Steps I have taken:

1. New RAID0 logical drive created with two new identical disks
2. Mount ISCSI drive on my PC, give it a drive letter, and share the drive with `Everyone` having full permission on the share
3. Boot from 2012 Essentials R2 media on server
4. Choose `System Image Recovery`
5. Choose Advanced and specify network share location on my pc
6. Enter credentials when requested for the connection
7. Message appears with `Scanning for system image disks`
8. The list is then empty, no images are found?!?

The connection to the share is working as far as I can tell, if I enter an erroneous path it errors with `path not found`.

Why is it not listing the backup image?? I can see the vhdx files in the backup folder under `WindowsImageBackup`.

Comment: For those coming here looking for an answer, I am sorry to say I never found one. I ended up re-building the server from scratch and using the back up to simply restore files.